# AJAX POST to RESTful service

Tags: ajax, rest

I have a login form and I am looking to post the input values to a RESTful web service and then the credentials are correct I show elements and hide the form but if they are incorrect an error message appears.

I want to do this via AJAX but I am hitting a stumbling block as all i am returning is an alert box with undefined inside. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="cp_LoginPanel fade-in form">
            <div class="in">
              <h1>Login</h1>
              <form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post">
                <label id="error">Sorry it seems your credentials are incorrect</label>
                <div class="inputBlock">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" id="username" />
                </div>
                <div class="inputBlock">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" id="password" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "Service Here",
                    dataType: JSON,
                    data: {
                        "username": username,
                        "password": password
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(e.Message)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: What is your issue?  Please add to your question details about what error you are seeing or what exactly is going wrong with this request.

Comment: I am looking for an 'error' or 'success' message but right now all i get returned is undefined.

Comment: Is an alert showing or where are you getting undefined returned to?  Please edit your question with more details about what issues you are facing exactly.

Comment: I have edited the question currently I am getting an alert which contains undefined.

Comment: change `alert(e.Message)` to `console.log(e)` (make sure you're watching the console when you run it).  It looks like you're running into an error but you're not accessing the message correctly.

Comment: Tried this the console is showing no errors which is weird. I have also tried console.log(e.Message)

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the answer to your problem. But im guessing you get and error and therefore try using the correct error parameters to get more information about your error.

The error function is called if the request fails. This functions receives 3 parameters.

- The jqXHR object
- A string describing the type of error that occurred
- An optional exception object, if one occurred

Try using the code below to print out your error the correct way. Look at the example below:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log('What is my error ' + textStatus);
   console.log('Is an exception thrown ?? ' + errorThrown)
}
```

Hope that you get more information about your error :)

PS.
You could also look at the answer in this question. It the excact same problem as yours :)
[jQuery Ajax - how to get response data in error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066790/jquery-ajax-how-to-get-response-data-in-error)

Comment: Perfect! The error I now receive is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Glad that i could help you. Feel free to marked the answer, if it solved your problem :)