# My restify POST error data isn't visible in the client JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, restify, http-error

I'm trying to implement a POST REST call in node.js using restify. In this instance, I want to send an error to the browser. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to send the error data so that the browser JavaScript can see the error data I sent.

When I call the doPost() function on the browser, it performs an ajax POST call to my server. The server code returns with an error 400 and a small JSON object containing an error message.

The browser then goes to the .fail() function. However, the textStatus is "error", errorThrown is an empty string, and the jqXHR properties are readyState : 0, responseText : "", status : 0, statusText : "error".

What can I do to get my error data from Node to the client browser?

Here is the jQuery code that runs in the browser:

```
function doPost() {

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3979/api/address",

    type: "POST",

    // Request body.
    data: {key: "mykey", address: "myaddress"}
})

.done(function(data) {
    // Show the formatted JSON in the text area.
    $("#outputTextArea").val(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})

.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // An error occurred. Display the error information.
    $("#outputTextArea").val(
        "status: " + jqXHR.status +
        ", textStatus: " + textStatus + 
        ", errorThrown" + errorThrown + "\r\n");
});
```

}

And here is the Node.js code that runs on the server:

```
const restify = require('restify');

// Create the server.
let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3979, function () {
    console.log(`${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});

// POST call that returns an error.
server.post("/api/address", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(400, {errorMessage: "The value given does not appear to be valid."});
});
```

Edit: Both `res.status(422); res.send("The value given does not appear to be valid.");` and `res.send(new BadRequestError('meh'));` fail in the exact same way. The jqXHR properties are the same (zero for readyState and status, empty string for responseText), textStatus is "error, and errorThrown is an empty string.

I tested my .ajax code against a known working POST call, and it gets proper values, including a JSON responseText.

Can someone please try this out in node.js and show me what I'm doing wrong, or show me the right way to send an error to the browser. So far, nothing works.

Edit: After further tests and experiments, this time with curl, I found that my POST call works and returns expected values.

I used this curl command to retrieve the status code:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -X POST http://localhost:3979/api/address
```

And received this response: `400`

I then used this curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3979/api/address
```

And received this response:

```
{"errorMessage":"The value given does not appear to be valid."}
```

So it appears that the problem exists on the browser end.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066790/jquery-ajax-how-to-get-response-data-in-error) seems to indicate a cross domain problem (page: www.mydomain.com/register, REST: server.mydomain.com/rest). However, I am doing all of this using localhost, so I don't see how the browser could see a cross domain issue here.

Any ideas on how to get REST POST errors to show up in the browser when running on localhost?

Comment: `res.status(422).send("The value given does not appear to be valid.");`

Comment: From the docs, `res.send(new BadRequestError('meh'));` see: http://restify.com/docs/response-api/#send